# Command line commands not executing?

Tags: cmd, command

Hello all well I have no idea why no commands will execute in my CMD.

[image]

i tried executing ping http://google.com and it tells me it's not recognized?

thanks.

Comment: Drop the http:// and try ping google.com

Comment: @Malcolm nop, still the same.

Comment: That's odd, I get an error when using http but works without :/

Comment: ping www.google.com??

Comment: @Malcolm again the same.

Comment: Can you ping other sites?

Comment: You could try resetting WINSOCK, http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-1650371/unable-run-ping-tracert-cmd.html

Comment: @Malcolm i just ran it and administrator and it worked, thanks.

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted :)

Comment: please check your `%path%` and compare it with the %path% in your "adminstrator"window. Looks like it is not, what it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Your `path` statement has changed.

Type `path` and see what it shows in a fresh command window